# How to get image from ip camera rtsp using gstreamer

Tags: c#, c, gstreamer, ip-camera

I am using the following command to get the image from ip camera using gstreamer.

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://ipaddress
:554/user=&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-cachi
ng=100" do-timestamp=true is_live=treu timeout=5 ! multipartdemux ! ffmpegcolors
pace ! jpegenc ! filesink location=test.jpeg
```

But i got only empty file. Kindly help me.

Comment: You are not decoding the stream? Are you even receiving an rtp stream(check by linking against a fakesink)?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should use a GStreamer 1.x version, the 0.10 versions are no longer supported and you're missing basically 3+ years of bugfixes, new features and other improvements.

But the problem in your pipeline is that you put the output of rtspsrc to multipartdemux. rtspsrc will output one or more RTP streams that have to be depayloaded, decoded, etc. Not multipart encoded data.

What you probably want is
rtspsrc uri=... ! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! filesink location=test.jpg

Note however that this will not just stop after the first JPEG picture but will append every received frame as JPEG picture to that single file. Use multifilesink instead of filesink if you want to create one file per frame.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I will check it out and get back to you.

Comment: Hi tried with this command gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="ipaddress:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100
" ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! filesink location=test.jpg  but i got error WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "ffmpegcolorspace" then i tried gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://ipaddress:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=100
" ! jpegenc ! filesink location=test.jpg file creating with 0 byte. no data. help me if i wrong.

Comment: In 1.x decodebin2 is called decodebin, and ffmpegcolorspace would be videoconvert. Also in your pipeline above you omitted the decodebin element.

Comment: Hi, can i get your mail or skype? i tried this but did not get it, got only empty image.. Looking forward your reply. as son as possible.Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, i tried this command gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://ipaddress:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_‌​stream--rtp-caching=100 " ! decodebin ! jpegenc ! filesink location=test.jpg. test.jpeg file cretaed with 0 byte. help me. Thanks.